# ASP.net core Blazor Server _ Client Architectural

Tags: asp.net, blazor, .net-5

Im beginer With Blazor , we work on system with back office and front users system that we done with MVC 5 but we want to upgrad to blazor with .Net5 , can i used Blazor Server Side as system back office and WebAssembly as Client user app if so can i set webAssembly with deferent Identify Autherntication from server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to understand that there are two flavors of Blazor.

1. Server side blazor -
   Where the browser is just a thin client and the user interactions are send over SignalR.
2. Blazor WebAssembly -
   The client application and the server is separated instances. For example you can create the client side as Blazor and the server side with php, node.js, asp.net core or what ever the requirement is. Just use the communication technology that both, server and client side can understand like REST API with json.

This is something you will need to decide what to pick mostly depending on the requirements. A good point for using server side blazor if your users are not having a larger ping than 200 ms from the server. Also the number of concurent users is a great factor. More than 5000 users at the same time can overload the server, this of course depends on the server hardware.
(Server side blazor is good for intranet projects where the net lag can be keep low.)

You can read more in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0).